# iTunes Does Not Automatically Sync

Tags: data-synchronization, windows, itunes

I just installed iTunes 9.2.5 (x64) on a new laptop, and iTunes is not automatically syncing when my iPhone is plugged in. The preference "Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically" is **UNCHECKED**. I didn't have this problem with my other laptop, so I'm not sure where the problem lays. Any help would be greatly appereciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your iPhone is bound to a specific machine. It won't automatically sync to a machine. You have to manually force it to sync. When you do this, it will ask if you wish to erase all data on your iPhone and sync with the new machine.

Beware, if you do this, it will wipe your contacts, music, apps, videos, etc, and replace them with what is on your current machine. The only way to avoid doing this is to copy your entire iTunes library folder from your old machine to your new one, and replace the existing library.

To summarise, the iPhone thinks your new laptop is a new machine, and so won't automatically sync to it until it's re-associated. Any questions, just shout.

Comment: I did copy the entire iTunes Library folder from the old machine to the new one. And iTunes did wipe and replace everything from the iphone again.

Comment: So to confirm, what you're saying is you've been through those steps already, without success?

Comment: Yes, I have been through those steps without success.

Comment: So, when the iPhone is connected, you are able to manually trigger the sync process, and that works fine, yes?

Comment: Yes, I can manually sync. (Sorry for the delay in answering).

Comment: I guess my next question would be - does iTunes 10 solve the issue? :-) Running out of ideas unfortunately. Does sound like an odd situation.

Comment: Huh. I upgraded to 10, and it seems that it does automatically sync again. Odd, very odd.

Comment: Excellent. Could perhaps have been corruption in preferences or something, but I'm glad it's fixed either way. Be sure to mark as answered if you're happy with the solution :-) (Albeit lucky)